# setting up git instaweb with nginx

Tags: git, nginx, gitweb

I'm trying to setup gitweb with `Nginx`.

But `git instaweb` supports very few web servers including httpd, apache, webrick etc.

I tried to use nginx as http daemon in git instaweb, but it failed.

```
[smit@smit-pc:/src/project]$ git instaweb -d nginx
Unknown httpd specified: nginx
```

I also tried to configure it in `.git/config` as given in git-instaweb man pages.

```
[instaweb]
                   local = true
                   httpd = nginx
                   port = 4321
                   browser = firefox
```

It's not working either. Is there any way or hack to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instaweb is a convenience setup script. For it to work it needs to know how to configure the webserver. Since nginx isn't supported you can't use it.
Instead you should read the `gitweb` manual and create your own configs from that information.

Comment: I checked `-d` param of apache2. It sets `serverroot`. In nginx there's no way to do that. (I saw `man nginx`). In nginx, new site must be explicitly added to sites-enable as vhost or in default host.